# Feeding your postgres database into graphite

Tags: graphite

How to feed object relational model postgresql database data into graphite? Is there any plugin available or is there any steps to convert the postgresql database into graphite. I am new to graphite. please tell me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try https://collectd.org/ - it has a Postgres plugin https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:PostgreSQL that will by default collect some useful system statistics and it is very easy to extend with your own custom queries.